# custom view on top of (overlapping) an imageview

Tags: android

I have a custom view and 2 imageviews.
I need the custom view to be between imageviews because they will overlap and then the custom view will move as an animation.

But when I place them as in the below xml , I get a "ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to  …"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5sp"
    tools:context=".FinalActivity" >

       <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView2"
          android:layout_width="776dp"
          android:layout_height="1154dp"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
    android:layout_marginTop="0px"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:src="@drawable/oven_alt" />     

      <com.aktuna.game.pizzadaisy.myviewx
        android:id="@+id/xview"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
      />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView1"
          android:layout_width="776dp"
          android:layout_height="1154dp"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
    android:layout_marginTop="0px"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:src="@drawable/oven_ust" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

---

this is the error I get :

```
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.game/com.test.game.FinalActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to com.test.game.myviewx
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to com.test.game.myviewx
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at com.aktuna.game.pizzadaisy.FinalActivity.onCreate(FinalActivity.java:49)
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
06-16 08:27:01.761: E/AndroidRuntime(23183):    ... 9 more
```

---

and here is my class for the custom view:

```
public class myviewx extends View
    {

        public myviewx(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public myviewx(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        public myviewx(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

            Resources res = getResources();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.base1);
            Bitmap brocoli = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.brocoli);
            Bitmap mint = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.mint);
            Random rand = new Random();            

            int x=500;
            int y=500;
            int radius=250;
            Paint paint=new Paint();
            // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
            canvas.drawCircle(x,x, radius, paint);
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD000C"));
            canvas.drawRect (250,250, 750, 750, paint); 
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);

            int xx[]=new int[15];;
            int yy[]=new int[15];;
            boolean dur=false;

            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                dur=false;
                int  x1 = rand.nextInt(500) + 250;
                int  y1 = rand.nextInt(500) + 250;
                x1=750;
                y1=750;
                canvas.drawBitmap(brocoli, x1-(brocoli.getWidth()/density), y1-(brocoli.getHeight()/density), paint);
                x1=250;
                y1=250;
                canvas.drawBitmap(brocoli, x1-(brocoli.getWidth()/density), y1-(brocoli.getHeight()/density), paint);

            }

        }


    }
```

---

```
public class FinalActivity extends Activity {

    myviewx z1;    

    public void adjustFontScale(Configuration configuration) {
        if (configuration.fontScale > 1.20) {
            configuration.fontScale = (float) 1.20;
            DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        adjustFontScale(getResources().getConfiguration());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final);

        z1 = (myviewx) findViewById(R.id.xview);

    }
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(z1, "translationX", 100f);
            animation.setDuration(5000);
            animation.start();
            }   
    }


}
```

is this really not possible ?
what can I do ?

Comment: Please post your FinalActivity.class also. it seems issue is there

Comment: Error is self explanatory `ImageView cannot be cast to com.test.game.myviewx`.

Comment: @Artipatel , I've added FİnalActivity.class to my question. can you please advise ? thx.

Comment: @ADM , I can see that. But I am not casting imageview to the named custom view. Why does it see it like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete your R file and then recompile.
That should fix it. The R file is generated automatically so don't worry. It is under /project/gen/package_name/R.java

Comment: Thanks. That really did the job. Wow that was really interesting.

Comment: happy to help .

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code and be sure about your custom view path specially in xml.

```
package com.androidtestapp;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class FinalActivity extends Activity {

myviewx z1;    

public void adjustFontScale(Configuration configuration) {
    if (configuration.fontScale > 1.20) {
        configuration.fontScale = (float) 1.20;
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    adjustFontScale(getResources().getConfiguration());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    z1 = (myviewx) findViewById(R.id.xview);

}
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(z1, "translationX", 100f);
        animation.setDuration(5000);
        animation.start();
        }   
}
```

}

==========================================================================

```
package com.androidtestapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.Random;

public class myviewx extends View
{

    public myviewx(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public myviewx(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public myviewx(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        Resources res = getResources();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground);
        Bitmap brocoli = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground);
        Bitmap mint = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground);
        Random rand = new Random();

        int x=500;
        int y=500;
        int radius=250;
        Paint paint=new Paint();
        // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
        canvas.drawCircle(x,x, radius, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD000C"));
        canvas.drawRect (250,250, 750, 750, paint); 
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);

        int xx[]=new int[15];;
        int yy[]=new int[15];;
        boolean dur=false;

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            dur=false;
            int  x1 = rand.nextInt(500) + 250;
            int  y1 = rand.nextInt(500) + 250;
            x1=750;
            y1=750;
            canvas.drawBitmap(brocoli, x1-(brocoli.getWidth()/density), y1-(brocoli.getHeight()/density), paint);
            x1=250;
            y1=250;
            canvas.drawBitmap(brocoli, x1-(brocoli.getWidth()/density), y1-(brocoli.getHeight()/density), paint);

        }

    }


}
```

===============================================================================

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="5sp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="776dp"
    android:layout_height="1154dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
    android:layout_marginTop="0px"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<com.androidtestapp.myviewx
    android:id="@+id/xview"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="776dp"
    android:layout_height="1154dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
    android:layout_marginTop="0px"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try your code and custom class of view gave me null pointer error I solve it.
So there is no any ClassCastException as you mention
You want custom image view on top and between two image views 
So try to change your xml layout as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
        android:layout_marginTop="0px"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/pax_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
        android:layout_marginTop="0px"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/preferred_airline_icon" />

    <com.demoapplication.customView.myviewx
        android:id="@+id/xview"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

By using FrameLayout we can get view above each other 
So try to just change the sequence of your view as per above layout

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is not what I am looking for. Framelayout is putting objects like they are on the same layer and no overlapping occurs. But I want them to overlap. Because some part of the custom view will be hidden initially below imageview. Then it will move and become visible. So, I need a solution with RelativeLayout.